# STATA georoute using HERE, no data prior to Jan 2020

Tags: here-api

I am using georoute with HERE API in Stata to calculate travel distance and travel time. To calculate travel time, date and departure time is included by using historic traffic data.

1. Using dates prior to January 2020 yields a warning that no historic traffic data prior to January 2020 is available by HERE.
2. Furthermore, if I calculate travel times with various dates from Jan 2020 to Jan 2022, it yields the exact same travel time for all dates & times for my toy examples. Whereas post January 2022, different days & times yield different travel times (Fridays, rush hour.. have longer travel times). I found online that only 365 days of traffic data are available.

Does anyone know if it is possible to access HERE traffic data prior to January 2020/ for more than the past 365 days?

Thank you!

Comment: It would be great if you can let us know which HERE API are you using and also share the complete request to investigate further. Thanks

Comment: Can you rephrase the two questions? Georoute "uses the HERE API (see https://developer.here.com) to retrieve distances in two steps. In the first step, addresses are geocoded and their geographical coordinates (latitude and longitude) are obtained. In the second step, the georouting distance between the two points is obtained" .  I have a HERE account and use an apikey, which is working, however traffic history is unavailable for dates more than a year ago.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can access HERE traffic data prior to January 2020. To request access to HERE Speed Data, use the [contact form](https://www.here.com/) on the HERE website. When your login has been established, you’ll be able to access the historical traffic data.

Note, Speed data is a historical data set covering 5 years. Additionally, it is available with only two days of latency from the date of collection. We have published blog on [Traffic Analytics Speed Data](https://www.here.com/company/blog/traffic-analytics-speed-data) which might help you understand the use case.

/MS